# How to specify phonetic keywords for IBM Watson speech2text service?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

While we have had good success with Bluemix Java SDK in the general case, we've bumped into problems while trying to recognize occasional non-English words (e.g., foreign last names).  Our hope was that one could specify the keyword list using SPR phonetic notation (which works great for text2speech), but that does not seem to be supported for speech2text.  Any suggestions/workarounds?

```
SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText();
service.setUsernameAndPassword("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

File audio = new File("C:\\Users\\AudioFiles\\euler.wav");    

RecognizeOptions options = new RecognizeOptions().Builder()
  .contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_WAV)
  .continuous(true)
  .inactivityTimeout(500)
  .keywords({"Agarwal", "Euler", "Qin"})
  .keywordsThreshold(0.5)
  .build();

  SpeechResults transcript = service.recognize(audio, options);
  System.out.println(transcript);
```

The objective is to be able say "My name is John Euler." and for the transcript not to return something like "My name is John Oyler." (which is what it does currently).

Thx.

Comment: Hi Robert, when you pass "Euler" in the list of keywords to look for, does it show up at all in the list of keywords found?

Comment: Thx Daniel.  That's what we were hoping for, alas no.  We get back: '"keywords_result": {}'.

Comment: Hmm, the three words that you pass are actually in the vocabulary, but maybe they are not found because they have very little weight in the language model. Have you tried relaxing the threshold? You can also try to use the Watson STT customization service to boost probabilities of names if the task is name focused

Comment: Daniel, indeed if I drop the threshold all the way to 0.15 I do get a match but with predictably low confidence (0.17).  You are also likely right on the prior probability in the language model being low.  I was not aware of customization service--will look into it.  Thx.

Comment: For reference, documentation for how to customize your language model can be found [here](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/custom.shtml)  Thanks, Daniel.

Comment: Daniel, that's exactly the answer we were looking for, thx.  Dictionary can be augmented and the pronunciation can be specified with sounds_like phonetic notation (rather than SPR, but's that is good enough for what we need).  But if your team is desperate for additional requirements: SPR as an alternative JSON tag would allow the user to indicate stress (e.g., 'Kumar vs. Ku'mar).

Comment: Hi Robert, I'm glad that helped, I will promote my comment to an actual answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, the three words that you pass are actually in the vocabulary, but maybe they are not found because they have very little weight in the language model. Have you tried relaxing the threshold? You can also try to use the Watson STT customization service to boost probabilities of names if the task is name focused