# Watson keyword spotting unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-watson, watson

I have downloaded the Watson unity SDK and set it up like show in the picture and it works.
My question is how do I add keyword spotting? 
I have read this question [For Watson's Speech-To-Text Unity SDK, how can you specify keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39940174/for-watsons-speech-to-text-unity-sdk-how-can-you-specify-keywords)
But I cant for example locate the SendStart function.

[image]

Comment: oh man, I would not enjoy hooking up Watson to Unity  :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Speech to Text service does not find keywords. To find keywords you would need to take the final text output and send it to the `Alchemy Language` service. `Natural Language Understanding` service is still being abstracted into the Watson Unity SDK but will eventually replace Alchemy Language.

```
private AlchemyAPI m_AlchemyAPI = new AlchemyAPI();

private void FindKeywords(string speechToTextFinalResponse)
{
    if (!m_AlchemyAPI.ExtractKeywords(OnExtractKeywords, speechToTextFinalResponse))
        Log.Debug("ExampleAlchemyLanguage", "Failed to get keywords.");
}

void OnExtractKeywords(KeywordData keywordData, string data)
{
    Log.Debug("ExampleAlchemyLanguage", "GetKeywordsResult: {0}", JsonUtility.ToJson(resp));
}
```

**EDIT 1**

`Natural Language Understanding` has been abstracted in tot he Watson Unity SDK.

```
NaturalLanguageUnderstanding m_NaturalLanguageUnderstanding = new NaturalLanguageUnderstanding();
private static fsSerializer sm_Serializer = new fsSerializer();

private void FindKeywords(string speechToTextFinalResponse)
{
    Parameters parameters = new Parameters()
    {
    text = speechToTextFinalResponse,
    return_analyzed_text = true,
    language = "en",
    features = new Features()
    {
        entities = new EntitiesOptions()
        {
            limit = 50,
            sentiment = true,
            emotion = true,
        },
        keywords = new KeywordsOptions()
        {
            limit = 50,
            sentiment = true,
            emotion = true
        }
    }

    if (!m_NaturalLanguageUnderstanding.Analyze(OnAnalyze, parameters))
        Log.Debug("ExampleNaturalLanguageUnderstanding", "Failed to analyze.");
}

private void OnAnalyze(AnalysisResults resp, string customData)
{
    fsData data = null;
    sm_Serializer.TrySerialize(resp, out data).AssertSuccess();
    Log.Debug("ExampleNaturalLanguageUnderstanding", "AnalysisResults: {0}", data.ToString());
}
```

**EDIT 2**
Sorry, I didn't realize Speech To Text had the ability to do keyword spotting. Thanks to Nathan for pointing that out to me! I added this functionality into a future release of Speech to Text in the Unity SDK. It will look like this for the Watson Unity SDK 1.0.0:

```
void Start()
{
    //  Create credential and instantiate service
    Credentials credentials = new Credentials(_username, _password, _url);
    _speechToText = new SpeechToText(credentials);

    //  Add keywords
    List<string> keywords = new List<string>();
    keywords.Add("speech");
    _speechToText.KeywordsThreshold = 0.5f;
    _speechToText.Keywords = keywords.ToArray();
    _speechToText.Recognize(_audioClip, HandleOnRecognize);
}


private void HandleOnRecognize(SpeechRecognitionEvent result)
{
    if (result != null && result.results.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (var res in result.results)
        {
            foreach (var alt in res.alternatives)
            {
                string text = alt.transcript;
                Log.Debug("ExampleSpeechToText", string.Format("{0} ({1}, {2:0.00})\n", text, res.final ? "Final" : "Interim", alt.confidence));

                if (res.final)
                    _recognizeTested = true;
            }

            if (res.keywords_result != null && res.keywords_result.keyword != null)
            {
                foreach (var keyword in res.keywords_result.keyword)
                {
                    Log.Debug("ExampleSpeechToText", "keyword: {0}, confidence: {1}, start time: {2}, end time: {3}", keyword.normalized_text, keyword.confidence, keyword.start_time, keyword.end_time);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently you can find the refactor branch [here.](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/tree/feature-config-refactor) This release is a breaking change and has all of the higher level (widgets, config, etc) functionality removed.

Comment: The Speech to Text service *does* support keyword spotting, but I think the Unity SDK might not yet.